# Resource shows Pending and From Cache in Google Chrome Network Tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, networking, web, browser-cache

I have two resource on my website (png files) that are showing as Pending when I load the page. However, the files did load properly. I guess this occurs because the images were loaded from the browser cache as displayed in the Size column.

Is it expected that a resource loaded from cache will show Pending in the Time column? If this is the case, why is this not the same for the deployment.js file? It shows it was loaded from cache but we can see it took 1ms to load. In this case, all three resources (js and pngs) have loaded successfully, hence the confusion. Thanks.

[image: Network tab showing resources in pending state]

Comment: I've started having this issue too. The thing that strikes me as odd is the 200 response code. That suggests that chrome as retrieved the file successfully from the server so I don't know why it would then try to get the file from the cache

Comment: @Edd Although I'm not sure why, it seems this means the resource was retrieved from cache...why other resources are not retrieved from cache and why others show response codes is unknown to me, but if you are concerned that the browser is failing to load these resources..I think it's safe to say it is loading them, but from cache....

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the resources that have pending next to them are from external domains. Could it be a cross domain 'issue'?

Anything retrieved from cache should still have a 'time' assigned to it, so it's not directly related to the fact it's from cache.